# JSON: Understanding format in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

Given the following JSON payload I would like to extract "023" from keyB->key2:

JSON Payload:

```
{
    "keyA" : {"lon": 139, "lat" : 35},
    "keyB" : [ {"key1" : "value", "key2" : "023"} ]
}
```

This is the code I apply:

```
    NSDictionary * subResults = jsonResult[@"keyB"];
    NSLog(@"VALUE: %@", [subResults valueForKey:@"key2"])
```

However the value is printed as following:

```
VALUE: (
    023
)
```

I want to get rid of the brackets "(". Am I approaching the extraction in the wrong way?

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  You have an "object" containing another "object" and an "array".  The "array" in turn contains an "object".  When you used `valueForKey` on an array you said "Give me an array containing all be values that  match "key2".  You got back an array (hence the enclosing `( )` characters) containing the only "key2" value found in the source array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your json as given is not valid son :( you have a quote to many. If we escape it like this:

```
{"keyA":{"lon":139,"lat":35},"keyB":[{"key1":"value\" clouds","key2":"023"}]}
```

Then, it's ok.
Now, what you have here is an son object, containing 2 keys (A and B). And KeyB is associated with a json Array
meaning :

```
 jsonResult[@"keyB"];
```

Does not return a NSDictionnary but a NSArray, containing 1 NSDictionary.
Now if you try to get the value "023", you should use

```
NSString str = jsonResult[@"keyB"][0][@"key2"]; // return "023"
```

and maybe

```
int twentyThree = str.intValue;
```

Comment: Though it would be better (more understandable) to not use `valueForKey` on the array but instead iterate through the array and use `objectForKey` on each dictionary in the array.

Comment: the code [subResults valueForKey:@"key2"] works because it's KeyValueCoding, meaning all the objects in the collection will perform the valueForKey: selector, however the result is an NSArray hence the parentheses in the logs

Answer (score 2):

The brackets show the value you want is inside an array.

```
NSData strAsData = …;
NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:strAsData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *subResults = jsonResult[@"keyB"];
NSDictionary *subSubResults = subResults[0];

NSLog(@"VALUE: %@", subSubResults[@"key2"]);
```

Because the array only has one item you can use a call to [-lastObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/lastObject) or [-firstObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/firstObject)

Comment: This is incorrect. The result of `jsonResults[@"keyB"]` is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy the key @"keyB" corresponds to `[{"key1":"value" clouds","key2":"023"}]`, this is a dictionary wrapped in an array (of one element). It is correct. Feel free to reverse your down vote at any time.

Comment: Your description in your comment is correct. The problem is that your code doesn't match the description.